# Ruby and Clojure: same algorith (?) but different results

Tags: ruby, clojure

I'm trying to decompose the square of a number into a sum of squares:
In Ruby:

```
    def decompose(n)
      def decompose_aux(nb, rac)
        return [] if (nb == 0)
        i, l = rac, nil
        while (i >= Math.sqrt(nb / 2.0).to_i + 1) do
            diff = nb - i * i
            rac = Math.sqrt(diff).to_i
            l = decompose_aux(diff, rac);
            if l != nil then 
                l  << i; return l
            end
            i -= 1
        end
        l
    end  

    l = decompose_aux(n * n, Math.sqrt(n * n - 1).to_i);
    if l then return l else return nil end 
end
```

In Clojure:

```
(defn decompAux [nb rac]
  (if (= 0 nb)
    ()
    (loop [i rac l nil]
      (let [diff (- nb (* i i)) rac (int (Math/sqrt diff)) l (decompAux diff rac)]
        (if (not= l nil) 
          (conj l i)
          (if (>= i 1)
            (recur (dec i) nil)
            nil))))))
(defn decompose [n]
  (let [l (decompAux (* n n) (- n 1))]
    (if l
      (reverse l)
      nil)))
```

In Ruby I get

```
decompose(7654321) --> [6, 10, 69, 3912, 7654320].
```

In Clojure:

```
(decompose 7654321) --> (1 1 2 3 11 69 3912 7654320)
```

The Clojure one is a tracing of the Ruby one but the results are different. Where is the default?

Comment: Not positive why they are different, but it is worth noting that both results are correct. The last three numbers are the same, and 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 11^2 = 136 = 6^2 + 10^2.

Comment: Yes the two decompositions are correct but why not the same with the "pretended" same algorithm? I wanted to avoid same numbers (1 1 ...) in Clojure as they are all different in Ruby.

Comment: Your Clojure version loops as long as `i` is `>= 1`, your Ruby version only as long as `i` is `>= Math.sqrt(nb / 2.0).to_i`.

Comment: I know but here that makes no difference in the result so I simplified the test in Clojure. Furthermore it seems that Clojure never uses this part with "recur"... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two algorithms are not actually the same.

The difference is that in Clojure you have a different loop condition (as pointed out by Tassilo Horn in the comments) and you check it at a different point in your computation. Consequently, the Clojure version can basically add as many 1s as necessary on to any candidate result which is not "complete" (that is, where the squares of the numbers add up to a number less than your target).

Actually this phenomenon is not limited to 1s – `decompose_aux(8, 2)` returns `nil`, whereas `(decompAux 8 2)` returns `(2 2)` – but the fact that you can always count down to the point where `i` is `1` means that `decompAux` is guaranteed to return an answer for any positive `nb` and `rac` inputs (an answer which might involve many 1s).

Here's a fairly direct translation of your Ruby to Clojure:

```
(defn decompose [n]
  (letfn [(decompose-aux [nb rac]
            (if (zero? nb)
              []
              (loop [i rac l nil]
                (if (>= i (inc (int (Math/sqrt (/ nb 2.0)))))
                  (let [diff (- nb (* i i))
                        rac  (int (Math/sqrt diff))
                        l    (decompose-aux diff rac)]
                    (if (some? l)
                      (conj l i)
                      (recur (dec i) l)))
                  l))))]       ; unnecessary line
    (decomp-aux (* n n) (int (Math/sqrt (dec (* n n)))))))
```

It matches the Ruby version on your example:

```
(decompose 7654321)
;= [6 10 69 3912 7654320]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Lots of thanks! Additional question: do you think that this result with a **strictly increasing sequence** is unique?

Comment: Sounds like a question for math.stackexchange.

Comment: No, you can evaluate `decompose_aux(7654321*7654321, 7654319)` to obtain an alternative strictly increasing sequence – `[3, 6, 11, 55, 5533, 7654319]`. The simplest example of a square having multiple such decompositions (strictly increasing and longer than the trivial decomposition with itself as the only member) is probably 169 = 13*13 = 3*3 + 4*4 + 12*12 = 5*5 + 12*12.

Comment: @user3166747 Accept the answer. Give him a tick!